# Generic duplication method

Tags: swift

I've had difficulty in the class finding much on introspection in Swift, so I'm out of ideas on this one. I currently have several classes that I want to be able to create clones of. Currently, I am having to write a lot of extra code for each class to have a unique duplication method.

Any advice out there on using generics and introspection to write a generic duplication method that I can just use for all classes I want to be cloneable?

To clarify further, [this](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/system/how-to-copy-objects-in-swift-using-copy) is essentially what I am currently doing - although I wasn't aware of the NSCopying protocol and instead made my own. I am hoping to avoid the need to pass all of the properties across to the new instance, however, and instead solve it using generics and introspection.

Comment: Any code you could show us?

Comment: Just edited to include a link to an article. The copy func in that article is almost exactly what I am currently doing in my code and am hoping to be able to avoid having to pass first name, last name, and age into the new instance manually.

Comment: Here is the link again: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/system/how-to-copy-objects-in-swift-using-copy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, but that is not possible. But this sounds like a great use case for value types. Any chance you can make them `struct`s instead of `class`es?

Comment: This is the correct answer almost anywhere where cloning is required.

Comment: It's worth noting that just making a type a struct won't always give the type value semantics. If the struct contains a class type property, your struct is essentially still a reference type and copies will be shallow.

Comment: @JackLawrence That's not true. A struct always have value semantics. If you put a reference type inside, you will get a copy of that reference type. That's what most `clone` implementations would do. That's why we distinguish between copying and deep copying.

Comment: @sulthan Consider an Array struct that holds a pointer to a buffer for its storage. If the contents of the buffer are not copied when the Array is copied and both array values now share same buffer, would you still say that the Array type has value semantics? I would not, since mutating one would affect both. (Swift's Array struct uses a buffer, but uses `isKnownUniquelyReferenced` to copy on mutation to preserve value semantics).

Comment: @JackLawrence is correct. In order to ensure value semantics, you must ensure your properties have value semantics (copy on write is one such strategy for reference properties). It has to be turtles all the way down.